# does LISTAGG in oracle handle number datatype

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a result as shown below

```
I_KEY 
10001
10002
10003
10004
10005
```

I need to modify the result to show output as

```
I_KEY
10001,10002,10003,10004,10005
```

I have written oracle function to return the aggregate result as shown below, My doubt is, will the LISTAGG handle value with **NUMBER** type?

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION GET_I_KEY(
 RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    TEST I_DETAILS.I_KEY%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT LISTAGG(I_KEY, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY I_KEY)
    INTO TEST
    FROM I_DETAILS 
RETURN TEST;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    TEST := NULL;
    RETURN TEST;
  END;
```

UPDATED FUNCTION

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION GET_I_KEY(
IN I_DETAILS.I_NAME%TYPE)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  TEST VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(I_KEY, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY I_KEY)
  INTO TEST
  FROM I_DETAILS ID ,I_TYPE IT
  WHERE ID.I_KEY = IT.I_KEY
  AND ID.I_NAME = IN;
RETURN TEST;
END;
```

Comment: No, You can't return the result of this `LISTAGG` as a `NUMBER` type. How can the string "10001,10002,10003,10004,10005" be a number.  if you replace ',' with '' it could work, but that's not what you want.

Comment: If LISTAGG cant be used with NUMBER then do we have any inbuilt functions in Oracle to handle NUMBER

Comment: Are you asking if you can pass numbers *into* `listagg()` ([as the *measure_expr*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm#SQLRF30030)), of the *result* will be a number? The first option is simple to test yourself; the second wouldn't make sense... If you are having an issue rather than asking a hypothetical question, then tell us what that issue is. Your function is missing a semicolon - no idea if that's a mistake posting the question, or is actually in your real code an throwing an error you're misinterpreting?

Comment: @Mahesh : I didn't say `LISTAGG` can't be used with `NUMBER`. I said the return value from your function can't be a comma separated string if it is defined as `RETURN NUMBER`.does that make sense?

Comment: @KaushikNayak  Will it be ok to make change in the function to return the result as VARCHAR , But the datatype of I_KEY is number in I_DETAILS table

Comment: @AlexPoole am testing it from my side

Comment: Yes. why not..? why don't you try  what u wish to do and let us know if you face any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm):

> The arguments to the function are subject to the following rules:
>
> - The measure_expr can be any expression. Null values in the measure column are ignored.
>     ...
>
> The return data type is RAW if the measure column is RAW; otherwise the return value is VARCHAR2.

The *measure_expr*, which is your `I_KEY` column in this case, can be a number. (The numeric values will be implicitly converted to strings). The result cannot be a number - as you are not passing in `RAW` data, it will be a `VARCHAR`.

The function you've posted has syntax errors which you may have introduced while posting, but with those corrected will get a run-time error because you've declared `TEST` as a number (via the `%TYPE` syntax).

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION GET_I_KEY
 RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    TEST I_DETAILS.I_KEY%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT LISTAGG(I_KEY, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY I_KEY)
    INTO TEST
    FROM I_DETAILS;
RETURN TEST;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    TEST := NULL;
    RETURN TEST;
  END;
/

Function GET_I_KEY compiled

select get_i_key from dual;

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "MY_SCHEMA.GET_I_KEY", line 6
```

You need to declare both`TEST` and the function return type as strings. You also don't need the exception handler - `listagg()` is an aggregate function so it will never return no rows; as there is no group-by clause it will always return exactly 1 row, which will be null if there is no data.

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION GET_I_KEY
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  TEST VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(I_KEY, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY I_KEY)
  INTO TEST
  FROM I_DETAILS;

  RETURN TEST;
END;
/

Function GET_I_KEY compiled

select get_i_key from dual;

GET_I_KEY                               
----------------------------------------
10001,10002,10003,10004,10005
```

---

If you have duplicate values in your raw data and you want to eliminate those from the result, you can just use a subquery; change the query inside your function to:

```
  SELECT LISTAGG(I_KEY, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY I_KEY)
  INTO TEST
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT I_KEY
    FROM I_DETAILS
  );
```

or with your modified function the same pattern:

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION GET_I_KEY(
  IN I_DETAILS.I_NAME%TYPE)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  TEST VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(I_KEY, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY I_KEY)
  INTO TEST
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT IT.I_KEY
    FROM I_DETAILS ID
    JOIN I_TYPE IT
    ON IT.I_KEY = ID.I_KEY
    WHERE ID.I_NAME = IN
  );

  RETURN TEST;
END;
/
```

although the join seems pointless - you can just query `I_DETAILS` unless you have orphan key values which don't appear in `I_TYPE` and you're trying to exclude those.

Comment: Thanks Alex ,that was really helpfull :)

Comment: @Mahesh - keep in mind the return data type: `varchar2`. That has a length limit of 4000 bytes (except in Oracle 12); once people learn about `listagg()` and start using it, exceeding that limit becomes the most common question they ask here and on similar sites. `listagg()` should be used far less often than it is.

Comment: Do we have any inbuilt function to select the distinct values  from LISTAGG ?

Comment: @mahesh - you mean re-tokenize the string you just constructed? If you are only using listagg to get a single object/variable you can pass around, look at collections instead, though even that may be doing more work than you really need - impossible to tell without knowing what you’re trying to do.(Or do you mean eliminate the duplicates from the string, but keep it as a string? Which can be done easily with a subquery in your function.)

Comment: @AlexPoole : my output is like "10001,10001,10003,10003,10005" just want to eliminate duplicate from the string, I think I got the answer, I can write a function to remove the duplicate

Comment: @mahesh - you don't need another function, you can just modify your current one so duplicates aren't included in the string in the first place. I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have just added updated function in my question and i have many more where conditions in the query

Comment: @mahesh - I'm not sure why - your current issue is not the one you originally asked about. Adapting what I'd already added to show using a subquery to get distinct values in the `listagg()` output to incorporate your join is also simple - though as `I_KEY` appears in both tables you have to specify which you're using, so presumably you're getting an error anyway. And the join seems pointless anyway. If you have further issues please ask a new question with your current function and issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157495/discussion-between-mahesh-and-alex-poole).